# Stay logged in with Firebase Authentication Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app that is already connected to Firebase and has an email/password login. However, when I log in to the app and close the app, it does not stay logged in. I've tried a few things from other threads (one of which is inside of my current code), but none of them have been successful. Anything helps, thanks!

LoginEmailViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginEmailViewController: UIViewController {

    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    
    @IBOutlet weak var loginEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginErrorLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setUpElements()
    }

    func setUpElements() {
        
        // hide error label
        loginErrorLabel.alpha = 0
        
        // style the textfields
        Utilities.styleTextField(loginEmailTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(loginPasswordTextField)
    }
 
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // TODO: Validate Text Fields
        
        // Create cleaned versions of the text field
        let email = loginEmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = loginPasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        // Signing in the user
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Couldn't sign in
                self.loginErrorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                self.loginErrorLabel.alpha = 1
            }
            else {
                // user signed in successfully, perform segue to tableViewController and set userDefault to true
                print("User signed in")
                
                self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()
                
                let vc = UITableViewController()
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInSegue", sender: nil)
                self.present(vc, animated: true)
            }

        }

    }
    
}
```

ProfileViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let data = ["Sign Out"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let signOutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign Out", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            do {
                try FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signOut()
                
                // switch screen to welcome screen
                self.userDefault.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()
                
                let vc = WelcomeViewController()
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logOutSegue", sender: nil)
                self.present(vc, animated: true)
                
                print("Successfully logged out")
                
            } catch let err {
                print("Failed to log out", err)
                Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Sign Out Error", message: err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .actionSheet, title: nil, message: nil, actions: [signOutAction, cancelAction], completion: nil)
    }

}
```

WelcomeViewController:

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signInFacebookButton: UIButton!
           
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // if user is already signed in, go to tabBarController screens
        if userDefault.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "currentUserSegue", sender: self)
            return
        }
        
        setUpElements()
    }

    
    func setUpElements() {
        let button = signInFacebookButton
        button?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        button?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 93/255, green: 129/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        button?.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        button?.tintColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

The "sign out" button is inside of the `ProfileViewController` and the "sign in" button is inside of the `LoginEmailViewController`. When "sign out" is clicked, it goes back to the welcome screen.

Comment: Can you explain how you determine that "it does not stay logged in"? So: from the code you shared, if you step through it in a debugger, which line doesn't do waht you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When I click log in, it shows in the debugger that it has successfully logged in. When I click log out, it shows in the debugger that it has successfully logged out. However, when I exit out of the app (close the app), even if I was previously logged in and in the ```ProfileViewController```, it automatically brings me back to the ```WelcomeViewController```. I want it to remain logged in and surpass the welcome/login screen if I've closed the app while being logged in. I also want it to remain logged out if I've closed the app while being logged out.

Comment: If you want to remain signed in, then don't sign out by calling `signOut()`.  That will remove everything the SDK knows about the user.

Comment: @DougStevenson, the user has a button to sign out. that is why there is a ```signOut()``` when they click it. that way they remain signed out if they click it. My problem is remaining signed IN.

Comment: If the user has expressed desire to sign out, why would you want them to remain signed in?  Let the user decide what they want.

Comment: I've already solved my problem with the help of @FrankvanPuffelen. I don't think you understood my problem. I wanted to keep the user Signed In if they had previously signed in, even if they closed the app, and to remain signed out of they had previously signed out, even if they closed the app. Before, I couldn't keep the user signed in if they had signed in (or in other words, they remained signed out when they close the app regardless if they had signed in previously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase automatically restores the user's authentication state when the app reloads. This is an asynchronous operation as it requires a call to the server, so your code will need to be set up to handle this.

So where you now have a call to `signIn(withEmail: , password: )` to handle the active sign-in, you'll also need a call to handle the restore of the authentication state in the form of an `addStateDidChangeListener`. From the documentation on [determining the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) comes this example:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

If you attach this listener when the app starts, it will initially be called with `null` for the user as the Firebase client starts to restore the state, then once the state is restored, it will fire with the actual user object.

In this callback you can then dispatch the user to the correct screen to handle their state.

Comment: do I only need to add it to the log in view controller or does it need to be in the Welcome view controller instead? Would it be in the viewDidLoad function? Also, can you show me how I'm supposed to implement it into my code?

Comment: This code is needed wherever you need to track the user's authentication status. It doesn't really matter in which VC you put it, but you'd use it there to then potentially redirect the user to the other VC based on their auth state.

Comment: it worked! Thanks so much, you're a lifesave!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @FrankVanPuffelen, I just added this to my `MainNavigationController`:

```
        // if user is already signed in, go to tabBarController screens
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
          if user != nil {
            // User is signed in. Show home screen
            let tabBarC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController") as! TabBarController
            tabBarC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(tabBarC, animated: false, completion: nil)
            print("User signed in, switched to TabBarController")
            
          } else {
            // No User is signed in. Show user the login screen
            let welcomeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
            welcomeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(welcomeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
            print("No user signed in, switched to WelcomeViewController")
            
          }
        }
```

This worked seamlessly and is extremely simple!